# A Group Isomorphic To The Direct Product Of Two of its Subgroups. Then are These Subgroups Normal?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product

> Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be subgroups of a group $G$.
>
> Assume that $G$ is isomorphic to $G_1\times G_2$.
>
> Then is it necessary that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are normal in $G$?

Clealry $G_1\cong G_1\times \{e\}\trianglelefteq G_1\times G_2$ and $G_2\cong \{e\}\times G_2\trianglelefteq G_1\times G_2$.

So it is easy to infer that $G$ contains normal subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ such that $H_1\cong G_1$ and $H_2\cong G_2$.
But does that force $G_1,G_2\trianglelefteq G$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $H$ be a non-normal subgroup of $G_1$ and $G_2\cong H$. Then $G=G_1\times G_2$ is isomorphic to $G_1\times H$ yet $H$ is not normal in $G$.

*Edit:* If the isomorphism $G_1\times G_2\to G$ is given by $(g_1,g_2)\mapsto g_1g_2$, then the answer is yes, $G_1$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: I assume you mean "$H$ is a non-normal subgroup of $G$ (rather than $G_1$)..." How are we sure that such a subgroup of $G$ exists?

Comment: No, I meant $G_1$. Explicit example: $G_1$ is the symmetric group $S_3$, $H=\langle (1\,2)\rangle\cong \Bbb Z/2$ and $G=S_3\times \Bbb Z/2$.

Comment: I could not follow your counterexample. Can you please mentions what are $G$, $G_1$ and $G_2$?

Comment: $G=S_3\times \Bbb Z/2$, $G_1=S_3$ and $G_2=\langle (1\,2)\rangle$ sitting inside $S_3$.

Comment: To be very precise, I believe you intended $G=S_3\times \mathbb Z/2$, $G_1=S_3\times \{e\}$, $G_2=\langle(12)\rangle\times \{e\}$, where $e$ is the identity of $\mathbb Z/2$. Thanks.